# MVC PartialView Cycles Back to Previous PartialView

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC Controller with an Index that will cycle through multiple `PartialView` as the user goes through the form process.

Here is the Index:

```
@section pageMain {
    <div id="partialView">
        @Html.Partial("SelectAccount", SUPR.Models.Account.GetAccounts());
    </div>
}
```

This works fine and I get the SelectAccount page just fine.

My issue is that I have an AJAX call that runs when the user selects a row in a table on the `SelectAccount` page. What is supposed to happen is that the `PartialView` is then replaced with another `PartialView` that displays the details of the selected row. This actually does work, but after about 1 second it cycles back to the `SelectAccount` `PartialView` with a query string attached, for some reason, to the URL.

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hs5Bk.png)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Km70w.png)

Here is the code for the AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Review/GetReviewView",
    data: { profitCenter: profitCenterNo }
}).done(function (data) {
    $('#partialView').html(data);
});
```

The ONLY that is happening in the controller for `GetReviewView` is that I'm returning the `PartialView` with the `PartialView` name and model. This working because, in that brief moment that I can see the `ReviewAccount` view, the proper data is in the fields.

Any thoughts as to why this odd behavior is occurring?

Comment: And, yes, I am totally open to other/better ways of doing this if you have suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you capturing the `event` in JS? If you are triggering off of a `click` event then add the `event` parameter to the method and then at the end of the method add:

`event.preventDefault()`

And see if it still happens. It sounds like a client side JS issue, not a C# issue.

The way you are doing this is actually fine. There used to be a Microsoft library called ASP-AJAX or something, don't remember because I didn't use it much. This library basically allowed you to decorate HTML elements with ASP-AJAX-METHOD , ASP-AJAX-REFRESH-TYPE and it would automatically  do something similar to what you are doing now. Go to the Server and retrieve a PartialView.

Comment: You are seriously my favorite person in the world at this very moment. I looked for hours on multiple posts about this, trying a myriad of different solutions that did nothing. One line, go figure :/

Comment: Haha no problem, I've had it happen to me too many times! Good luck!